# How can I overlayfs the root filesystem on linux?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, mount, overlays

I'm using [`overlayFS`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt) to create a sort of simple experimental sandboxing.
I think I understand how it works:

- *lower* layer should be always mounted R/O
- *upper* layer is where all changes happen
- *work* layer is for transactional reasons
- *target* is where all merged *lower* + *upper* go

As example, I have a physical disk mounted on `/disk2`. Then I want to overlay to preserve the contents, so I can do something like:

```
mount("overlay", "/disk2", "overlay", MS_MGC_VAL, "lowerdir=/disk2,upperdir=./upper,workdir=./work");
```

This works just fine: when my new process tries to amend content under `/disk2`, then it will only amend in reality under *upper*: this is indeed working as intended. For example, I can also see the *0, 0* files to show that something is deleted in the *upper* but not in the *lower*.

Unfortunately looks like I can't somehow overlay on root `/`: if I execute the following code:

```
mount("overlay", "/", "overlay", MS_MGC_VAL, "lowerdir=/disk2,upperdir=./upper,workdir=./work")
```

I can still see the whole *real* `/` and when I write files, they get written in their *real* (i.e. *lower*) location, not in the *upper* one.

What am I doing wrong here?

I am on kernel `4.4.0-53`.

Comment: An overlay root file system needs to be performed by init (or systemd or earlier) to ensure that all processes would use this `/`, rather than the `/` of the real device. All processes have an inherent concept of `/`, and you can't alter it once the process has been created (I'm open to correction on this). You should look at details of [overlayroot](https://github.com/chesty/overlayroot) [blog posting](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/10/protecting-ubuntu-root-filesystem/).

Comment: @petesh Not sure how much it helps because I need to do this dynamically after the _clone_ call in C code. Will have a look nonetheless.

Comment: I remember a presentation by a company at the euro linuxcon from last year in Dublin which used something like that - I can only remember the presentation happened - names evade me at the moment. You may be able to find something online related to it.

Comment: If you can run 'init' from an initramfs, mount your read-only "real" root partition and your writable partition some where in the initramfs file system.  I'm doing this on a system I maintain with a command along the lines of `mount -t overlayfs none -o lowerdir=$ro_rootfs,upperdir=$writeable /mnt/overlayfs`.  After that point, you may need to do some bind-mounts of your proc, sysfs, and devfs into /mnt/overlay, and then `exec chroot /mnt/overlay /init` to kick of the "real" init. Like @Petesh was getting at, this is how you alter the location of `/` for everything forked from `init`.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316018/how-to-use-overlayfs-to-protect-the-root-filesystem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to what I've read I don't think it's possible to *programmatically* do this once the system is started.

Answer (score -1):

prior-art: If you like one, then this is not for you...

ex.
...previous `/` partition: /dev/nvme3n2

save your root partition to an image file (ie... dd if=/dev/nvme3n2 of=/free_2_be/2022-12-11-awesome.im bs=44M oflag=direct status=progress)

mount the overlay filesystem to '/' (REALLY not necessary in init *(1) ); then initiate `pivot_root`  ...glory.

** realize that you can never go back if you choose `switch_root` ...now, don't not never say that nobody didn't provide you with a disclaimer.  In regard to the site's privacy policy and whatnot: viking created the word 'law' **

*(1) derived inference from a retrospective regarding that kind of overlay in init, indicates that that kind of thing, in that circumstance, is a problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).